# Only seeing half of a 2tb drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I ran the live cd (14.04) before I decided to dump windows (upgraded to 16.04). It saw two of my three storage drives a 1 and 2tb but it has always seen the 2tb as a drive with two partitions ("partition 1" 134MB and a 1TB free space) and never mounted it. Windows 7 never had any issue accessing this drive which is over half full. Ubuntu has no issue with my other 2tb WD drive which is nearly identical.

My bios also seems to be confused, I tried switching from IDE to AHCI to see if that'd fix it but it doesn't. The mb is an ASUS SABERTOOTH 990FX R2.0.

I installed testdisk but it warns not to use it if the size detected is different from the actual size so I didn't proceed.

Thanks

-CLARIFICATION EDIT-

Here are screenshots of gparted:

What it should look like:

[image]

And the drive I'm having issue with:

[image]

They're both internal SATA drives.

Comment: What do you mean by "see a drive"? Which tools are you using to look?

Comment: What kind of drives? How are they connected (ie: direct SATA, external enclosure, USB2, USB3). Are 2TB disks in similar enclosures (if external)? Please post gparted screenshots of your 3 drives. Cheers, Al

Comment: I've edited the post to include more information with two screenshots of the two drives that are almost identical.

Comment: The Linux kernel seems to think that the second drive is only ~1 TB large, but since the partition table advertises a partition with ~2 TB it takes the safe route and doesn't mount the file system instead of risking inconsistencies and data corruption. What do you plan to do with that drive? Do you need any of the data on that drive? Depending on the answer to that we can continue making plans. It would also help insofar as your “question” doesn't contain an actual question (one reason why it's on hold as unclear).